# Split a column with a mix of concatenated and not concatenated items delimited by comma over a list

Tags: python, lambda

I am working with a dataframe that contains a column with concatenated and not concatenated items:

| Name | Group | Average Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | A, D, T, F | 10 |
| Lukas | A, D, T, F | 20 |
| John | A, D, T, F | 5 |
| Mary | B, G, Y, Z | 15 |
| Lukas | B, G, Y, Z | 25 |
| John | B, G, Y, Z | 50 |
| Mary | K | 12 |
| Lukas | L | 23 |
| John | M | 56 |

I have a group list with:

```
group_list = ['D', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M']
```

I want the Average Age value for all names over this list, but firstly I'd like to split Group column.

I've tried:

```
if ',' in df['Group']:
    new_df['Group'] = df['Group'].str.split(",").apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(set(group_list)))[0])
    else:
        new_df['Group'] = df['Group']
```

I also tried:

```
 new_df['Group'] = df['Group'].str.split(",").apply(lambda x: [list(set(x).intersection(set(group_list)))[0]] for ',' in df['Group'] else df['Group'])
```

But I am not able to run, Kernel always crash.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: besides of splitting, how are you going to calculate average (considering the current values of `Average Age`)?

Comment: I won't. I will get Average Age column values, Roman. No calculation needed in my case.